# How to change the value of an attribute in an XML document?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML document below and there is a tag called `<FormData>` in side this tag it as an attribute called **FormId**="d617a5e8-b49b-4640-9734-bc7a2bf05691"

I would like to change that value in C# code?

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(MapPath(tempFolderPathAlt + "dvforms" + "\\XmlDataTemplate.xml"));
    //Change value of FormID
    xmlDoc.Save(tempFolderPath + "data.xml");
```

Be is my XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FormData Platform="Android" PlatformVersion="100" Version="966" DataVersion="1" Description="Investec - Res" FormId="d617a5e8-b49b-4640-9734-bc7a2bf05691" FileId="e6202ba2-3658-4d8e-836a-2eb4902d441d" EncryptionVerification="" CreatedBy="Bob" EditedBy="Bob">
<FieldData>
<request_details_export_template Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"></request_details_export_template>
<request_details_reason_for_valuatio Mod="20010101010101" IncludeInPDFExport="Yes"></request_details_reason_for_valuatio>
</FieldData>
<Photos Mod="20010101010101"/>
<VoiceNotes/>
<Drawings Mod="20010101010101"/>
<FieldNotes/>
</FormData>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this, including:

```
XmlAttribute formId = (XmlAttribute)xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//FormData/@FormId");
if (formId != null)
{
    formId.Value = "newValue"; // Set to new value.
}
```

Or this:

```
XmlElement formData = (XmlElement)xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//FormData");
if (formData != null)
{
    formData.SetAttribute("FormId", "newValue"); // Set to new value.
}
```

The SelectSingleNode method uses XPath to find the node; there is a good tutorial about XPath [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp). Using SetAttribute means the FormId attribute will be created if it does not already exist, or updated if it does already exist.

In this case, FormData happens to be the document's root element, so you can also do this:

```
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("FormId", "newValue"); // Set to new value.
```

This last example will only work where the node you are changing happens to be the root element in the document.

To match a specific FormId guid (it is not clear if this is what you wanted):

```
XmlElement formData = (XmlElement)xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//FormData[@FormId='d617a5e8-b49b-4640-9734-bc7a2bf05691']");
if (formData != null)
{
    formData.SetAttribute("FormId", "newValue"); // Set to new value.
}
```

Note that the select in this last example returns the FormData element and not the FormId attribute; the expression in [] brackets enables us to search for a node with a particular matching attribute.

Comment: +1 For recommending XPaths, there's plenty of information to Google on XPaths and it's usually better than trying to traverse each node.

Answer (score 5):

To select the right node use following XPath `//Node[@Attribute='value']`.

In your case the missing piece of code could look like:

```
var formId = "d617a5e8-b49b-4640-9734-bc7a2bf05691";
var newId = "[set value here]";

var xpath = String.Format("//FormData[@FormId='{0}']", formId);

XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);

if(node != null)
{
    node.Attributes["FormId"].Value = newId;
}
```

See XPath [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) or check this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp).

Comment: +1 for showing how to search for a FormId matching a specific guid.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could walk the tree explicitly:

```
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.GetAttribute("FormId").Value = "";
```

Comment: +1. Note this assumes that the FormId attribute already exists; alternatively, "xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("FormId", "newValue");" will add the FormId if it does not already exist, or change it if it does.

Comment: Yup, this is a very simple example, but you can alter it for your own purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SetAttribute method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.setattribute.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(m_pFileName);                 
XElement xElemAgent = doc.Descendants("TRAINEE")
.Where(arg => arg.Attribute("TRAINEEID").Value == m_pTraineeID.ToString()).Single(); 
xElemAgent.SetAttributeValue("FIRSTNAME",m_pFirstName);
xElemAgent.SetAttributeValue("LASTNAME", m_pLastName);
xElemAgent.SetAttributeValue("DOB",m_pDOB);
xElemAgent.SetAttributeValue("UNIQUEID",m_pUniqueID);
doc.Save(m_pFileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to create a function that can be reused anywhere you like:

```
public void ReplaceXMLAttributeValueByIndex(string fullFilePath, string nodeName, int index, string valueToAdd)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fullFilePath);
        fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
        fileInfo.Refresh();

        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(fullFilePath);
        try
        {
            XmlNode node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode(nodeName);
            node.Attributes[index].Value = valueToAdd;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            //add code to see the error
        }
        xmldoc.Save(fullFilePath);
    }
```