# Replace a value in an XML file

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I'm trying to load an XML file, replace a specific value, and then save the file.

Here is what the file looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PremiereData Version="3">
  <Project ObjectRef="1" />
  <Project ObjectID="1" ClassID="62ad66dd-0dcd-42da-a660-6d8fbde94876" Version="36">
    <Node Version="1">
      <Properties Version="1">
        <ProjectViewState.List ObjectID="2" ClassID="aab0946f-7a21-4425-8908-fafa2119e30e" Version="3">
          <ProjectViewStates Version="1">
```

I'm trying to update the 4th line in the example - with `Version="36"`. The problem I'm having is that the 36 integer changes from file to file and it could have any number. And also the file has a few instances of the string Version. So how do I replace that first version?

Here's what I tried:

```vb
Dim gzFile As String = "C:\users\desktop\delete.txt"
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
Dim xmlReader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(gzFile)
doc.Load(xmlReader)
Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("PremiereData/Project/Project")

MsgBox(doc.SelectSingleNode("PremiereData/Project/Project".ToString))

For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
    MsgBox(node.Attributes("Version").Value.ToString)

    If node.Attributes("Version").Value.ToString Is "36" Then
        MsgBox("found")
        node.Attributes("Version").Value = "16"
    End If
Next

xmlReader.Close()
doc.Save(gzFile)
```

Comment: Is it distinguished by being the first `<Project>` element with attributes `ObjectID`, `ClassID`, and `Version`, or is it the first `<Project>` element with attribute `ObjectID="1"`, or is there something else about it which makes it unique?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the value of an attribute in an XML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083044/how-to-change-the-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-xml-document)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the value of the `Version` attribute of the first `Project` element which has `ObjectID='1'`, you can do something like this:

```vb
Imports System.Xml

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim src = "C:\temp\project.xml"
        Dim doc As New XmlDocument
        doc.Load(src)

        Dim n = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Project[@ObjectID='1']")
        If n IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim attr = n.SelectSingleNode("@Version")
            If attr IsNot Nothing Then
                attr.Value = "Look here!"
            Else
                ' Perhaps do something if it is a problem there is no "Version" attribute.
            End If
        Else
            ' Perhaps do something if it is a problem there is no Project with ObjectID='1'.
        End If

        doc.Save(src)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PremiereData Version="3">
  <Project ObjectRef="1" />
  <Project ObjectID="1" ClassID="62ad66dd-0dcd-42da-a660-6d8fbde94876" Version="Look here!">
    <Node Version="1">
      <Properties Version="1">
        <ProjectViewState.List ObjectID="2" ClassID="aab0946f-7a21-4425-8908-fafa2119e30e" Version="3">
          <ProjectViewStates Version="1">
          </ProjectViewStates>
        </ProjectViewState.List>
      </Properties>
    </Node>
  </Project>
</PremiereData>
```

Note that the attribute value is a string and it is the interpretation of it that would be an integer (in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Loop over all the nodes checking if `Node.Attributes ("Value")` is `Not Nothing` then do whatever you want with it.

Like this

```
Dim gzFile As String = "C:\users\desktop\delete.txt"
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
Dim xmlReader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(gzFile)
doc.Load(xmlReader)
Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("PremiereData/Project")

Dim found As Boolean = False
For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
    If (Not node.Attributes ("Value") Is Nothing) Then
        If (node.Attributes("Version").Value.ToString  = "36" ) Then
            MsgBox("found")
            node.Attributes("Version").Value = "16"
            found = True
        End If
        If found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next

xmlReader.Close()
doc.Save(gzFile)
```